# Import Set of Doubles to an Array From File C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, ifstream

What I'm attempting to accomplish, is to open an external .dat file using "ifstream" then read each double into a vector array.

What I have:

```
//Setup I/O
ifstream fileIn;
ofstream fileOut;

//Define vector for file data
vector<double> fileData;

fileIn.open("/FilePath.../checkIn.dat");
//If opening failed, display this text.
if (fileIn.fail( ))
{
    cout << "    Input file opening failed.\n";
    //stop program
    exit(1);
}
```

The file I'm reading from:

```
2000 1 1225.72 1 463.81 3 200 1 632 2 1500 1 300 2 1800
```

I've been looking all around the internet, can't find something useful. 
I'm looking for a function similar to "hasNextDouble" in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're trying to imitate Java too closely (i.e., make things much more complex than necessary).

```
// Open the file
std::ifstream file_in("/FilePath.../checkIn.dat");

// Create the vector, initialized from the numbers in the file:
std::vector<double> fileData((std::istream_iterator<double>(file_in)),
                              std::istream_iterator<double>());
```

...and you're done.

Comment: love it. Simple and concise. Now if it was just that easy for user defined types LOL

Comment: When I use that code I receive the following errors:

    No matching constructor for initialization of 'vector<double>'

And

    Expected ')'

after the very end of the line.

Comment: @BrillianceOfBen: Oops -- I missed a paren. I've put a [mildly modified version](http://ideone.com/JEACS0) online for testing (modified to read from `std::cin`, since that's the only input supported, and write sorted output to `std::cout`, to show that it read successfully).